# Better way than current query to assemble random categorized entries?

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I am trying to display exactly 6 random 'entertainment' entries, but with my current query it's getting a random number between 1 and 6, and displaying that number of entries. How do I update this query in order to make it display exactly 6 random entertainment entries from my Articles table? Also, I don't want to do ORDER BY RAND() because my table will become bigger overtime. Here's my current query:

```
SELECT
    r1.*
FROM
    Articles AS r1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Articles)) AS id) AS r2
WHERE
    r1.id >= r2.id
    AND r1.category = 'entertainment'
LIMIT 6;
```

Table structure:

```
table Articles
- id (int)
 - category (varchar)
 - title (varchar)
 - image (varchar)
 - link (varchar)
 - Counter (int)
 - dateStamp (datetime)
```

Comment: Do you have gaps in your `id` column?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, for example id: 1 is categorized as lifestyle, id: 2 is categorized as entertainment, id: 3 is categorized as Science, and so forth. When the query collects all of the entertainment categories, all of those ids are numbers with gaps between them.

Answer (score 0):

With

```sql
select floor(rand() * m.maxId + 1) as randomId
from Articles a
join (SELECT MAX(id) maxId FROM Articles) m
limit 100
```

you will create 100 random ids. I take 100 because you have gaps in you id column, so the probability of not getting enough existing ids will be (very) small. Then you can use that result to select only 6 rows with those ids:

```sql
select distinct a.*
from (
    select id, floor(rand() * m.maxId + 1) as randomId
    from Articles a
    join (SELECT MAX(id) maxId FROM Articles) m
    limit 100
) r
join Articles a on a.id = r.randomId
order by r.id -- only need it for small tables. will slow down the query on big tables
limit 6
```

The best value for `LIMIT` in the subselect depends on percentage of gaps in your ids. 100 should be enough and fast.

**Update**

If you need to filter by `category` you can add a `WHERE a.category = 'entertainment'` clause before `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. But in that case you will need to ajust the number of generated random ids.

For example: If you have inserted 1M articles but 10% of them are deleted, then an average of 90 randomly generated ids do really exist. If now 10% of articles have `category = 'entertainment'`, then an average of 9 random rows will match the condition. *Average* means - it might be 3 and might also be 16. So you need to generate more random ids to be sure, that you get at least 6 articles. With `LIMIT 1000` in the subselect you will get an average of 90 random entertainment articles. This way you are very unlikely do get less than 6. So you need to know the statistics of your table in order to pick a good `LIMIT`.

Another issue with the `WHERE` clause, is that MySQL might reverse the join order to use an index for filtering. This might be faster for small number of generated random ids, but might be slower if the `LIMIT` in the subselect is huge. You can force the join order by using `STRIGHT_JOIN` instead of `JOIN` - But in my test with `LIMIT 10000` it didn't make a 
measurable difference.

If your condition is too selective (e.g. only 1% of articles have `category='entertainment'`) a simple `ORDER BY RAND()` can be faster, because otherwise you would need to create too many random ids. But up to 10K rows matching your condition `ORDER BY RAND()` will be fast enough.

Comment: So it will only get the first 100 ids? What if I have more than 100 ids? Also, I want to get entertainment entries, this query doesn't specify in the WHERE

Comment: No.. it generates 100 random ids. You can take any Other table than `Articles` for that subselect that has at least 100 rows. You only need it to create a set of 100 dummy rows to generate one random number each.

Comment: Is the set @preLimit included inside the query? Also, what is the m for in the query?

Comment: Sorry, `LIMIT` doesn't work for `IN (..)` clause. Neither does a session variable for `LIMIT`. So i'll change that to use a `JOIN`.

Comment: The blank page went away, and 6 entries are showing, but there are duplicate entries that are showing as well

Comment: Every subselect needs an alias. `m` is the alias for the most inner subselect, which i use to get the highest id (`maxId`)

Comment: There should not be any duplicates if the `id` is unique

Comment: All ids are unique, but for some reason it's showing duplicates. How would I add the WHERE clause for category = 'entertainment'?

Comment: You're right - there might be duplicates, so i added `DISTINCT`

Comment: Filtering by `category = 'entertainment'` could be complicated because i don't know the percantage of rows matching that condition. I have overseen that condition in your question first - Sorry.

Comment: Right now, I have 7 rows with category = 'entertainment'. Updating your query did make it distinct, but it also made it so I don't get exactly 6 entries displayed. Sometimes 3 entries are displayed, sometimes 4, it's displaying entries 1-6 random entries on refresh

Comment: This is a strange behaviour on small tables. It seams MySQL is sorting the generated random ids before the join, so you only get the numbers from 1 to 6. This issue can be solved by using the `id` of the subquery to sort the outer select (see update). But i wasn't able to reproduce the problem selecting less than 6 rows. And i still don't have a solution for the category condition.

Comment: That's weird, it's still doing the same thing by printing off 1-6 entries. Hmm, I think since I won't have a large table until about 3 months, i'll just stick with ORDER BY RAND(), even though I really don't want to  do it...

Answer (score 0):

Your 'entertainment' entries should all have unique id's which should be integers.

If this is the case you could generate 6 random int's between 1 and the amount of entries you have using PHP's rand() function. Here is a function I've written which may be useful.

```
function selectSixRandomEntries() {
    $queryWhere = "";
    $i = 0;

    while($i < 6) {
        $randomNumber = rand(1, 200);
        if (strpos($queryWhere, $randomNumber) == -1)
            continue;

        $queryWhere .= "r1.id = " . rand(1, 200);
        if ($i != 5)
            $queryWhere .= " OR ";

        $i++;
    }

    return $queryWhere
}
```

And to use it you could try

```
$query = "SELECT
    r1.*
FROM
    Articles AS r1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Articles)) AS id) AS r2
WHERE
    " . selectSixRandomEntries() . " 
    AND r1.category = 'entertainment'
LIMIT 6";
```

Comment: For some reason, I am getting a blank page after adding your code in and adjusting it, the part of the query where it says 'WHERE " . selectSixRandomEntries() . " is this exactly how it's supposed to be laid out?

Comment: It should be `=` instead of `==` and `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: Thank you Paul, I've fixed it up now.

Comment: However, you will only get ids from 1 to 200 and you could hit deleted ids.

Comment: Ah sorry user2896120, try adding it now. See if it works after my update.

Comment: @Acidic Hmm, I just did, the blank page went away, but none of the entries are displaying for some reason